# Detect call events in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, call

I have seen some examples on how to detect incoming/outgoing call events on background in iOS. Apparently, I have to use `CTCallCenter`.

1. Will this solution work only for iOS 10+/swift 3?
2. Will I be able to open the app immediately after the call has ended?
3. Will I be able to record calls? Starting with what iOS version this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes this class is available in iOS 10.
2. No, you can only detect a phone call while in the foreground.
3. No, this is not really possible, you might be able to start recording sound but only the user mic.

Comment: Is this class also available in lower versions?

Comment: As you can read in the documentation for [`CTCallCenter `](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretelephony/ctcallcenter) tis is available from iOS 4 to iOS 10 when it got depricated. For iOS 10 and higher you should use [`cxcallobserver`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit/cxcallobserver)

Comment: Can you also clarify what means 'foreground' in ios? If I start application, then press home button, will it still be in foreground?

Comment: No, once the you press the home button goes into the background.